# How to write an "indefinitly expanding list" in CodenameOne?

Tags: list, codenameone

I have a list of items, that contains an list of objects of its own type. Something like this:

```
class MyObject {
   List<MyObject>
}
```

This Object can inhibit itself indefinitly deep. That means, Its structure could be similar to this:

```
Object1 [
  Object1.1 [
    Object1.1.1 [
       ...
        Object1.1.1....n []
    ]
  ]
]
Object2 ...
...
Objectn
```

(Notice: this is not a structure that I created, neither do I like it, but my company said, that I need to handle this design in mobile as well)

So I imagined, that I could try to pack these into a list of objects, that expands onClick. Just like the expandable list in android. As the list needs to expand over and over again, I am not sure if it is possible to implement this using codename one and if yes, how could a list like this be rendered and modelled? how should the onClick be forwarded to the corresponding item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a Tree structure, take a look at the Tree component:
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html

Comment: looks good, but:
1) I will not know about the depth of the tree as I do not want to load all objects at once as I get them via REST and dont want to cache them all at once 2) can I add a custom look, like a renderer so they look prettier?

Comment: You don't need to load all objects, you need to implement a TreeModel and to custom the look override the Tree createNode method